# Noise doesn't play music [Solved]

Tags: applications

I have a problem with Noise.
When I try to play music the programm say that there isn't the codecs and it trays to install them.
The codecs are already installed but the system doesn't recognise them.
I have the same problem with Audiance playing videos.
Thanks.

Jusuf

Comment: Hey, I guess you are new to StackExchange, welcome :). To mark a question as solved it's best practice to click the checkmark next to an answer (below the downvote button). This makes it more visible for other users and supporters. Here is some more info on ["Accepting Answers: How does it work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to install the ubuntu restriced extras. This package contains some codecs.

**First, be warned that it might not be legal in some countries, because of software patents.**

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```